# Group homology in degrees zero and one using the standard resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I'm trying to show using the standard resolution that for any group $G$, 
$$
H_0(G) = \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } \quad H_1(G) = \frac{G}{[G,G]}.
$$

(I already know this holds, as by definition it is $H_\bullet(G) = H_{\bullet}(X)$ with $X$ a $K(G,1)$ space: these are always path connected, and by Hurewicz's theorem we get $H_1(X) = \pi_1(X)^{ab} = G^{ab}$. However, this exercise explicitly asks for the computations to be done with the standard resolution and so I want to get to understand it.)

So, we start with the chain complex

$$
\cdots \xrightarrow{d_n} C_n \to C_{n-1} \xrightarrow{d_{n-1}} \cdots \to C_1 \xrightarrow{d_1} C_0 \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} \mathbb{Z} \to 0 
$$

where $C_n$ is the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by $G^{n+1}$ with its $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module structure given by the action $g(g_0,\dots,g_n) := (gg_0,\dots,gg_n)$, and the differentials are defined by

$$
d_n : (g_0, \dots,g_n) \in C_n \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i(g_0,\dots,\widehat{g_i},\dots,g_n) \in C_{n-1}.
$$

Hence I want to compute the homology in degrees zero and one of

$$
\cdots \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_2 \xrightarrow{1 \otimes d_2} \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_1 \xrightarrow{1 \otimes d_1}\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_0 \to 0.
$$

So far, I have proved that:

- $\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_0 \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ simply because $C_0 \simeq \mathbb{Z}[G]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, with basis $(1)$.
- We have $1 \otimes d_1 = 0$. In effect: as any element of $C_1$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-linear combination of elements of the form $(1,g)$, it suffices to note that 
  $$
  \begin{align}
  1 \otimes d_1 (n \otimes (1,g)) &= n \otimes [(g)-(1)] = n \otimes (1) - n \otimes (g) = n \otimes (1) - n \otimes g(1) \\
  &= n \otimes (e) - gn \otimes (1) = 0.
  \end{align}
  $$
  because the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.

From here one can see that $$H_0(G) = \frac{\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_0}{\operatorname{im}1 \otimes d_1} = \frac{\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_0}{0} = \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_0 \simeq \mathbb{Z}.$$

I also know by a direct calculation that

$$
\begin{align}
1 \otimes d_2(n \otimes (1,g,h)) &= n \otimes [(g,h) - (1,h) + (1,g)]\\
&= n \otimes [(1,g^{-1}h) - (1,h) + (1,g)].
\end{align}
$$

and so

$$
H_1(G) = \frac{\ker 1 \otimes d_1}{\operatorname{im} 1 \otimes d_2} = \frac{\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_1}{\operatorname{im} 1 \otimes d_2} = \frac{\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_1}{<n \otimes [(1,g^{-1}h) - (1,h) + (1,g)]>_{n \in \mathbb{Z}, \ g,h \in G}}
$$

So far, I've failed to come up with a good description for $\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} C_1$ and $\operatorname{im} 1 \otimes d_2$.

Any hints on how to continue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have pointed out, in $\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z[G]}C_1$ you have the relation
$1\otimes(g,h)=1\otimes(1,g^{-1}h)$. Then $\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z[G]}C_1$
is the free Abelian group on the symbols $1\otimes(1,g)$, which I'll denote
by convenience $[g]$. Then $H_1(G)$ is the quotient of
$\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z[G]}C_1$ by the symbols $[g^{-1}h]-[h]+[g]$, as you point out. That is $[g]+[k]-[gk]$ where $k=g^{-1}h$. So $H_1(G)$ is the quotient
of the free Abelian group on $G$ by the relations $[gk]=[g]+[k]$. That's
just the Abelianisation of $G$: $G/[G,G]$. In more detail, $G\mapsto H_1(G)$
via $g\mapsto [g]$ is a homomorphism, and as the target is Abelian, it factors
through $G/[G,G]$, so in effect is a map $G/[G,G]\to H_1(G)$. Considering the
map going the other way taking $[g]$ in the free Abelian group over $G$ to
$g[G,G]\in G/[G,G]$ yields the inverse map.